# Powershell: select XML node value into variable by element index

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have this PowerShell script which I use to parse through different aspects of an XML-file. Therefore, I Would like to retrieve the value of a specific XML-node and save it into a variable. This node I would like to select, exists multiple times in the XML-file, so I need to be able to mention the specific number of the node I want to retrieve.

XML-file:

```
<lvl1>
    <lvl2>
        <lvl3>
            <lvl4>test1</lvl4>
            <lvl4>test2</lvl4>
            <lvl4>test3</lvl4>
        </lvl3>
    </lvl2>
</lvl1>
```

Powershell scripts I've tried:

## 1 returning nothing and no errors

```
[xml] $response = get-content "FilePath\Resp.xml"
[string] $Var = $response.SelectSingleNode('lvl1/lvl2/lvl3/lvl4[2]').InnerText
```

## 2 returning error: "cannot index into a null array."

```
[xml] $response = get-content "FilePath\Resp.xml"
$Var = $response.lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4[2].'#text'
```

Comment: The third `<lvl4>` is terminated with another `<lvl4>` instead of `</lvl4>`.  I assume that's not in the original file?  With that fixed, `$response.SelectSingleNode('lvl1/lvl2/lvl3/lvl4[2]').InnerText` and `$response.lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4[2]` (no `.'#text'`) work for me on PowerShell v5.1.18362.145.

Comment: Have you considered using [Select-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7) ?

Comment: Missed the edit timeout, but I should add the first snippet returns `test2` and the second (modified) returns `test3`.  Which are you trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) essentially provided the crucial pointers in comments on the question:

Using **PowerShell's dot notatio**n *directly* returns the text content of leaf elements (elements with only a text child node), so there's **no need for `'.#text'`**:

```
# Note: `.lvl4` is an *array* provided by PowerShell, so the index is 
#       0-based. Therefore, [2] retrieves the *3rd* element.
$response.lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4[2]  # -> 'test3'
```

Note that PowerShell exposes the multiple `lvl4` elements as an *array*, so **indexing** into that array is **`0`-based.**

---

Your **XPath**-based command should work as-is, but note that **indices in XPath are `1`-based**, so `[2]` would refer to the *2nd* element:

```
$response.SelectSingleNode('lvl1/lvl2/lvl3/lvl4[2]').InnerText # -> 'test2'

# Equivalent commands:
$response.SelectSingleNode('lvl1/lvl2/lvl3/lvl4[2]').'#text'
$response.SelectSingleNode('lvl1/lvl2/lvl3/lvl4[2]/text()').Value
```

Comment: Made a typo in the path that leads to the node. Rather stupid. All your solutions did indeed work!